# WALA: Errors in starting examples

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to wala. Trying to configure it by following steps given at wala: gettingstarted.

However, I have to face errors on each example I am trying to run. Please look at following errors:

1- Example  SWTTypeHierarchy

> PANIC: roots.size()=0

2- Example PDFTypeHierarchy

> spawning process [C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/dot.exe,
>   -Tpdf, -o, D:\WALAOut\th.pdf, -v, D:\WALAOut\temp.dt] process terminated with exit code 0 read 919 bytes from error stream

3- Js frontend com.ibm.wala.cast.js.rhino.test-JUnit
I am not able to use launcher instead when I open it following error is there

> " [JRE]: Unknown JRE type specified:
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType"

I am not sure which step went wrong which have completely damage the execution. Please help

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help you with these generic problems. I will give it a try based on the limited information these error messages contain.

1) have you configured your wala.properties file?

2) you are missing dot for this visualization. Hence the error. You may also want to use http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/ to view your graphs.

3) seems like a problem with the location of the jre, how did you configure your properties file?

The WALA examples are great to learn from, but sometimes getting one of them to run is more time consuming, than using the slicer example in their wiki page:
http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/UserGuide:Slicer

This should get you started more easily.